# Creating admin guard VS using the default guard for both users and admins

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-passport, guard

Since [I had problem with Passport multi auth](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161), I wonder is it necessary to have an admin guard (and an admins table) or it's better to use the default guard (and users table) for both admins and users with the help of role and permissions? Which is better?

Answer (score 1):

That's a really hard question to answer without more information, but I'll try looking at it from a few perspectives:

**You have an application that has users that can turn into admins (and vice-versa)**

In this situation, I would probably have a single table that contains an `is_admin` column and use the column to validate whether the user can perform administration tasks (e.g. by using Laravel's [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization)). The downside to this is that if you wanted to create a third type of user (e.g. supervisor), you would need to change the model used.

**You have an application where users are completely separate from administrators**

If you control the administrators and everyone else is just a user, creating separate guards could be used, this does allow for a lot of flexibility in the future if you wanted to implement different authentication flows for both administrators and users (for example, using SAML). If you were to add a third type of user (e.g. supervisor), you could then just create another guard.

**You have an application that can have different (customisable) permissions for each user**

In this case I would recommend implementing a `roles` table, a `permissions` table, a `role_permissions` table and adding a column called `role_id` to the `user` table. This provides the most flexibility and is also usable with the Laravel's [gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization) system, but is probably the most difficult to setup and hardest to maintain.

For the application I develop, we use a mixture of roles and guards. We use roles for users as each user gets a customisable set of permissions. We then use a separate guard for API users which inherit the permissions of the user they were authenticated with.

Comment: Thanks, can setup and maintain for the third option get easy with https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission ?

Comment: @Ali that library looks like it would work, but it's not too difficult to roll your own too (no pun intended). You can setup the tables like I mentioned in the post and then create two new models (Role and Permission) which relate to each other and provide a relationship to the User model. You then just need to create a way of customising the permissions and adding the permission checks in and you're good to go.